# How could I code to work function?

Tags: c

### Code

```
typedef struct 
{
    int *x;int *y;
}point;

void move(point *p) 
{
    (*p).x=(*p).x+1;
    (*p).y=(*p).y+1;
}
int main()
{
    point p;
    p.x = 10;
    p.y = 5;
    printf("%d, %d\n", p.x, p.y);
    move(&p);
    printf("%d, %d\n", p.x, p.y);
    return 0;
}
```

### Detail

I want to output 10,5 and 11,6 but it shows me 10,5 and 15,9. What's wrong with my code?

Comment: Why `(*p).x` instead of the more normal `p->x`?

Comment: This code shouldn't work, you're deep into undefined behaviour. You have a struct with int pointers, but those values are never allocated. You just randomly stomp memory. That struct should contain plain `int` values, not pointers.

Comment: What can you change to fix your problem? The code of the function? The declaration of the struct type? The code of main()?

Comment: Please always enable warnings in your compiler. Assigning an integer to a pointer or passing a pointer to `printf` while format specifier is `"%d"`should give some warnings. And warnings are valuable hints, what is wrong with your code.

Answer (score 1):

You have very little idea of what a pointer is. `int*` means it will contain the address of the `int` variable. `p.x = 10` is saying that, assign 10 to this pointer variable. Then you are printing that pointer with wrong format specifier.

Then you have incremented those pointer. Accessing this would be disaster. And it's not strange that `+1` on pointer will move it by `sizeof(int)`. So the value you saw is `14` and `9`.

```
typedef struct {int x;int y;}point;
```

This is what you have wanted for sure. Also other thing that is already mentioned is `(*p).x = p->x`. That's it.

---

You are wrong when you said output is `15,9` it will be `14,9`. `sizeof(int) = 4` in your system. To provide some more information pointers should be printed using `%p` format specifier like this.

```
int *p;
...
printf("%p\n",(void*)p);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
I implemented this code and i got the output like this 10,5 and 14,9

there is 2 alternative ways to get the output like this 10,5 and 11,6 

    typedef struct 
{
    int *x;int *y;
}point;


replace the code with this :

`typedef struct 
{
    int x;int y;
}point;`

or

typedef struct 
{
    char *x; char *y;
}point;
```